# The GET method is not supported for this route api.php

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5, routes

I'm trying to make APIs using laravel. They are working fine on localhost but when I upload them to my server they give me error

> 405  Method Not Allowed

routes/api.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::post('logout', 'API\LoginController@logout');

Route::resource('users', 'API\UserAPIController');
```

Controllers\API\LoginController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\API\APIBaseController as APIBaseController;
use DB;
use Validator;
use Hash;

class LoginController extends APIBaseController
{

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {       
        $user_id=$request->user_id;
        $user = User::find($user_id);
        if (is_null($user)) {
            return $this->sendError('User not found.');
        }
        User::where('id', $user->id)
        ->update([
            'imei_no'=>'',
            'device_id'=>''

        ]);
        return $this->sendResponseArray($user_id, 'User successfully logout.');
    }
}
```

Postman Screenshot (Server Run) Where error is showing

[image]

Postman Screenshot (Localhost Run) Successfully executed

[image]

I have already tried many answer posted on Stackoverflow but didn't find any solution

**EDIT:**

I tried direct POST method function inside Routes but getting the same error so nothing related to Controller

```
Route::post('testPost', function(){
    echo "Inside POST";
});
```

Comment: As per my understanding, you didn't deploy the code correctly on the server

Comment: Make sure your domain is hitting the laravel public directory.

Comment: Already checked my controller is hitting properly

Comment: In your route, you have defined the method to be GET and in POSTMAN, you are using POST, are you getting this error because of that?

Comment: are you referring to the middleware route? I already tried removing it but didn't get any success

Answer (score 0):

use any , may helps

```
Route::any('logout', 'API\LoginController@logout');
```

Comment: with ::any it is going in get method after that my parmas 'user_id' is not carried out in Controller

Comment: where from you are getting $user_id? if you are getting $user_id from $request object then use if($request->method() == 'POST'){ ... }

Comment: updated my question as i missed to mentioned one line here

Comment: now your request is post ? if yes, then insert your code in if(request->method()=='POSt'){} this condition executes when your request is post. otherwise get will executed. for GET request you can use **else** block.

Comment: are you submitting a form with action="POST" ? or sending a query parameter with url?

Comment: I'm testing it with POSTMAN and sending param with POST field  and  with request->method()  it is giving GET call even I run postman with POST method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204550/discussion-between-goldy-agarwal-and-kamlesh-kumar).